# How to specify OCL time constraints?

Tags: uml, embedded-systems, real-time, ocl

The article [An OCL Extension for Real-Time Constraints](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.25.4701&rep=rep1&type=pdf) describes and interesting extension to OCL for the specification of time constraints.

New types `OclConfiguration` and `OclPath` are defined along with a new `post()` operation which is able to generate a set of possible `OclPath` for a specified time interval.

At pag. 18, the article presents an interesting example:

> We first request that new workpieces have to periodically arrive at
>   the input buffer within time intervals of at most 100 time units. In
>   other words, state Loading can always be reached within 100 time
>   units. The corresponding OCL expression is:
>
> ```
> context Buffer
> inv: Loader@post[1,100]->forAll(p:OclPath | p->includes(Loading))
> ```

From my understanding, the previous expression declares the invariant that all the possible `OclPath`(s) in the interval between 1 and 100 time units have to include the state `Loading`.  Whereas I believe that the correct expression shall state that all the possible `OclPath`(s) generated after 100 time units have to contain the state `Loading`:

> ```
> context Buffer
> inv: Loader@post[100]->forAll(p:OclPath | p->includes(Loading))
> ```